# error DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_READ linux

Tags: linux, swift

I have compile swift-corelibs-libdispatch on Ubuntu 15.10. Most of the gcd functions seem to work. However, when I try to use `DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_READ`, I get a compile error `error: use of unresolved identifier 'DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_READ'`.

I have a simple example that you can run from docker:

```
docker run -it saltzmanjoelh/swiftubuntu:20160301.0.0 /bin/bash -c "git clone https://github.com/saltzmanjoelh/gcd4/ && cd gcd4 && swift build -Xcc -fblocks"
```

Does anyone know how to fix this compile error?